# Find rotation axis in 3D space with quaternions

Tags: 3d, rotations, quaternions

Rotation of $u_1$ around $q_1$(unknown) axis is $u_2$, and rotation of $u_2$ around $q_2$(unknown) axis is $u_3$.
What is the value of axis $q$,in case $q$=$q_1$=$q_2$?

Note that possible values of $q_1$ makes a circle,$c_1$, in 3d space,and $q_2$ another circle,$c_2$, in 3d space.
Question is to find the intersection($q$,unit vector) of these circles, $c_1$ and $c_2$.

related to question in [find quaternion scalar from end points of the rotation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2191514/find-quaternion-scalar-from-end-points-of-the-rotation)

Comment: @jyrki-lahtonen  wondering if you know the answer for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Axis of rotation of $q_1$ is $c_{1} = u_1 \times u_2$.

Axis of rotation of $q_2$ is $c_{2} = u_2 \times u_3$.

The two circles intersect at $\pm (c_{1} \times c_{2})$ normalized to unit length.

Comment: in your case $c_1$ is a possible vector from the solution set,as well as $c_2$,imagine there are 2 circles in 3D space having the same center,if you pick random vectors from each as $c_1$,$c_2$, and consider a case $c_1$,and $c_2$ are very close to to the intersection point then $c_1$x$c_2$ will be close to perpendicular of intersection point, which also sates the intersectin may not be at the vectors ±($c_1$x$c_2$)

Comment: yes, if $\pm (c_{1} \times c_{2})$ is nearly zero, then the three vectors are yearly in the same plane.